# Massive format of numbers in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I have a huge file with numbers in cells and unfortunately, they have a wrong format. They have a space in thousands separator and LibreOffice recognize it as a text.

For example this is one number: 3 597 961

What can I do to fix it without change it manually one by one? As it is now, I cannot apply any formula in the calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search and replace:

- select all columns and/or rows and/or cells you want to changes.
- edit, find&replace
- Put a "space" in "search for"
- Click "Replace all"

All spaces will disappear, and all fields that are now only digits and a decimal sign will align up to the right side of the cell (making them numbers).

[image]

---

With your example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Damn..You are awesome genius. So simple, but sooo good :) Thank you. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes, after the time limit!

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris all the simple answers are the best ones :D